# Asp net core api looped entity doesn't show in looped result

Tags: asp.net, json, rest, api, asp.net-core

For a school project, we have been working on an asp.net core RESTful API. And have run into a problem showing specific entities. We added a functionality where you can go deeper into the entity, to include its relations. For example, we have an entity called Invoice, which has a Customer. And a Customer has multiple invoices. 
So when we include customer and the invoices for that customer you would expect all the invoices to be displayed. Instead of that happening, it shows all the invoices except for 'highest' entity (as shown below).

```
[
   {
      "invoiceId":1,
      "customer":{
         "customerId":1,
         "name":"Aron",
         "kvkNumber":"12345",
         "invoices":[
            {
               "invoiceId":2
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   {
      "invoiceId":2,
      "customer":{
         "customerId":1,
         "name":"Aron",
         "kvkNumber":"12345",
         "invoices":[
            {
               "invoiceId":1
            }
         ]
      }
   }
]
```

As you might be able to see, the customer that belongs to invoice id 1 does not have invoice id 1 as a part of its invoices
We have been looking at some JSON serializing options, but we have not been able to find one that solves this in a pretty way. we have tried

```
options.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.All;
```

But this changes the whole layout of the json output.

Does anyone have any good way of solving this problem?

Comment: Share us the model defination for `Customer` and `invoices` and the the query code you used to get this result.

Comment: Here is the model definition https://drive.google.com/open?id=1R6dQq3IQbRuBm22lIzmDLjaJ2pxE10JS

Comment: For the query code I use the Entity framework from asp.net core. Where I use include to get all the relations. var dbSet = _context.Set<Invoice>().AsQueryable(); dbSet = dbSet.Include("Customer.Invoices");